How can i create validation condition in Job Requisition for Part time workers should less than or = 30 scheduled hours
I have a Validation where i need to have a condition while creating a job requisition in workday. When the initiator selects Part time as time type a c alert or an Error should pop up statingtha " Part time workers should have less than or = 30 Scheduled hours
I have a Validation where i need to have a condition while creating a job requisition in workday. When the initiator selects Part time as time type a c alert or an Error should pop up stating that " Part time workers should have less than or = 30 Scheduled hours.
